# Converting image to grayscale in WordPress using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, image-processing

I'm trying to customize a WordPress plugin which has a function that I wish to add the action to convert colored images to grayscale. I learned that `imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE)`does the trick. But I can't seem to get it to work.

```
public function stream_photo( $image_path, $src, $key, $user_id, $coord, $crop ) {
    $image = wp_get_image_editor( $image_path ); // Return an implementation that extends WP_Image_Editor

    //DEBUG
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);

    $quality = UM()->options()->get( 'image_compression' );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $crop ) ) {

            if( ! is_array( $crop ) ) {
                $crop = explode(",", $crop );
            }

            $src_x = $crop[0];
            $src_y = $crop[1];
            $src_w = $crop[2];
            $src_h = $crop[3];

            $image->crop( $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h );

            $max_w = UM()->options()->get('image_max_width');
            if ( $src_w > $max_w ) {
                $image->resize( $max_w, $src_h );
            }
        }

        //DEBUG
        //echo "Image path is: " . $image_path;
        //$image = wp_load_image($image_path);
        //imagefilter($image_path, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);

        $image->save( $image_path );

        //DEBUG
        //imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);

        $image->set_quality( $quality );

        //DEBUG
        //echo "Image path is: " . $image_path;
        //$image2 = wp_load_image($image_path);
        //imagefilter($image2, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error( esc_js( __( "Unable to crop stream image file: {$image_path}", 'ultimate-member' ) ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What isn't working about it? Try to narrow down your problem, and let us know what you find.

Comment: Ok, got it. I just turned on debugging. Error is "imagefilter() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in ...."

Comment: @DavidCulbreth I got rid of the error by doing this, $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path); imagefilter($image_res, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE); imagejpeg($image_res); But now the final image does on appear on the webpage and there's no error whatsoever. Not in debug.log or webpage.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth When I removed imagejpeg($image_res); it's back to normal as shown here, https://prnt.sc/ohnmb3 but the image is not grayscale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this lines of code:

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor( $image_path ); // Return an implementation that extends WP_Image_Editor

//DEBUG
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
```

[wp_get_image_editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_image_editor) return a [WP_Image_Editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor) object, but [imagefilter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) require only 'image resource'. The change below should work.

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor( $image_path ); // Return an implementation that extends WP_Image_Editor

$im = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE)){
    // Convert to grayscale
    imagefilter(imagecreatefrompng($image_path), IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    // Save image
    imagepng($im, $image_path);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

That's for PNG, should you catch all image extension instead of PNG only.

Comment: Thank u so much. This works when I place your code right at the end, not after $image = wp_get_image_editor( $image_path );